# how to combine "where" and "starAt" and "limit" in one query [FIREBASE ,REACT NATIVE, REDUX]

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I'm trying to build a infinite scroll , these are the functions I'm using  , I have two functions I'm using `fetchDistrubutors()` and  `fetchMoreDistrubutors()` , the first one works like expected but the second's query is returning null in onSnpashot  :
initial fetch (works fine)

```
async fetchDistrubutors(arg,state){
            try {
                const fetch_limit = state.distrubutor.fetch_limit
              
                
                const distrubutorsResponse= await firestore()
                                        .collection('users')
                                        .where('type','==','DISTRUBUTOR')
                                        .limit(fetch_limit)
               
                distrubutorsResponse.onSnapshot(res=>{
                    if(res.docs.length)
                    {
                        const distrubtors = res.docs.map(doc=>doc.data())
                        dispatch.distrubutor.fetcheddistrubutors({
                            distrubutors:distrubtors,
                            last_visible : res.docs[res.docs.length-1].id
                        })
                    }
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            
        },
```

this where I'm having trouble the `LoadMore` function , the query res return null , I 'don't know what what I'm doing wrong

```
async fetchMoreDistrubutors(arg,state){
            try {
                const fetch_limit = state.distrubutor.fetch_limit
                const last_visible = state.distrubutor.last_visible

                console.log({last_visible})
                console.log({fetch_limit})

                const moreDstrubutorsResponse= await firestore()
                                        .collection('users')
                                        .where('type','==','DISTRUBUTOR')
                                        .orderBy('id',"desc")
                                        .startAt(last_visible)
                                        .limit(fetch_limit)
               
                moreDstrubutorsResponse.onSnapshot(res=>{
                    if(res == undefined) return 
                    console.log(res)
                    if(res.docs.length)
                    {
                        const PrevDistrubtors =  state.distrubutor.distrubutors
                        const newDistrubtors  = res.docs.map(doc=>doc.data())
                        dispatch.distrubutor.fetcheddistrubutors({
                            distrubutors : [...PrevDistrubtors,...newDistrubtors],
                            last_visible : res.docs[res.docs.length -1].id
                        })
                    }
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second query includes `.orderBy('id',"desc")` , which the first does not. They are *not* the same query, and are *not* in the same order.

Comment: but its necessary otherwise 'm getting an error

Comment: The point isn't to *remove* it from the *second*; the point is to *add* it to the first